# A contradition on local time for Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion and $L_t$ its local time at zero. Setting $\beta_t=\int_0^t\text{sgn}(B_s)dB_s$, it is well-known that
$$L_t=|B_t|-\beta_t$$
Now defining $X_t=\beta_t+L_t$, we obviously have that $X_t=|B_t|$, in particular $X_t$ is a non-negative process.

If I now applay the generalized Ito formula to the process $|X_t|$ I obtain the following contradiction:

$$|X_t|=X_t+1/2 L_t$$

and so $L_t$ is the zero process.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: To use the (generalized) Ito formula you need a twice cont. differentiable function $f$...

Comment: also : the correct generalization of Ito's formula in this context is $|B_t|=\beta_t+L_t$ (which is Tanaka's formula). Since we know already that this holds nothing like $L_t=0$ can be deduced.